# why nginx reserve proxy upstream is a static website, there are many TIME_WAIT? how to slove

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core

the nginx config:(the config is for aspnet core, but now test for a static website on iis)

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:81;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

after every times access http://localhost from chrome, TIME_WAIT + 1.

this both happened on windows 10 + nginx and ubuntu 16.04 + nginx

why this happened? how to slove this? for help

i tried change the kernel config, but that isn't what i want, i need to know why this happened? is my nginx config lead this? or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are concerned about port exhaustion. You should change your proxy_pass to use an upstream block, and then enable a keep-alive pool on the upstream. eg:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:81;
    keepalive 20;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    ...
}
```

Also have a look at the NGINX blog: https://www.nginx.com/blog/overcoming-ephemeral-port-exhaustion-nginx-plus/

Comment: thanks @TuxInvader, in my test, only one client, and request 10 times,  every request TIME_WAIT + 1

Comment: You will always get time wait once the connection has closed, this is standard tcp behaviour. It's not a problem unless you run out of ephemeral ports. Using keep-alives in an upstream pool should allow tcp sockets to stay open and serve multiple clients.

Comment: I did another test: windows server 2008 r2 + iis (reverse proxy) + asp.net core, iis as a reverse proxy, TIME_WAIT will not be generated, I am confused?

Comment: this cause by nginx:
`
TCP    127.0.0.1:12284        127.0.0.1:81           TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12285        127.0.0.1:80           TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12287        127.0.0.1:81           TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12289        127.0.0.1:81           TIME_WAIT       0
`
 can u help me @TuxInvader

Comment: upstream keepalive slove my question. thanks @TuxInvader